# Sufficient conditions for $x,Ax,A^2x,...,A^{n−1}x$ being linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n×n}$, and all entries in both of them are non-negative. Moreover, we have
$$\mathbf 1^Tx = 1,$$
$$\mathbf 1^TA = \mathbf 1^T.$$
What is a sufficient condition for
$$x,Ax,A^2x,...,A^{n−1}x$$
being linearly independent?

Comment: The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A-\lambda I & x \end{bmatrix}$ has full rank for eigenvalues of $A$ (Popov Belevitch Hautus test.)

Comment: Whoa, the question changed.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Your notation doesn't make much sense: if $1$ is an identity matrix then it is equal to its transpose $1^T$. If $x$ is a vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then $1^Tx = x$, which is a vector and not an identity matrix.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: @Rob 1 is a column vector of ones in this context, except on the right hand side of the first equation